# Combining Rows Based on A Column, Keep the Rest of the Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to consolidate multiple rows in excel into one row, based on the values in a column.  I want the rest of the values in the row, if present, to be copied to the new row.

Example:

```
Name      Database1     Database2      Standard
ALLEY     AL            FALSE          FALSE
ALLEY     FALSE         ALY            ALY
ANNEX     FALSE         FALSE          ANX
ANNEX     ANNX          ANNX           FALSE
```

I want this to be changed into:

```
Name      Database1     Database2      Standard
ALLEY     AL            ALY            ALY
ANNEX     ANNX          ANNX           ANX
```

Bonus if you can do it without VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

- I would split each column off into its own table.
- I would sort each table.
- I would delete the false data:

```
Name   Database1   Name1   Database2   Name2   Standard
ALLEY   AL          ALLEY   ALY         ALLEY   ALY 
ANNEX   ANNX        ANNEX   ANNX        ANNEX   ANX 
ALLEY   FALSE       ALLEY   FALSE       ALLEY   FALSE               
ANNEX   FALSE       ANNEX   FALSE       ANNEX   FALSE
```

And then I would re-combine them into one table again:

```
Name    Database1   Database2       Standard
ALLEY   AL          ALY             ALY
ANNEX   ANNX        ANNX            ANX
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in cell A1 you can paste the following formula in any cell of your spreadsheet:

`=IF(OFFSET(A$1; ROW(A1)*2-1; 0)<>FALSE;OFFSET(A$1; ROW(A1)*2-1; 0);OFFSET(A$1; ROW(A1)*2; 0))`

By dragging the fill handle you can extend the range to your needs.